# The only int variable won't _POST

Tags: php, mysql, variables, post

And I again I have to deal with PHP and MySQL :) So, I've got a mysql table and want to have "add" feature. So I can edit my table from browser easily. So far I have done nearly everything but the problem is that variable consisting "number" from my table (or id) won't _POST to other page. It won't _POST directly from textarea or even if I put it in a hidden field(well, have just understood that this is pretty much the same).

Let me show you some examples:

```
  $a = mysql_query("SELECT number FROM peoples ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 1");
  $number_a = mysql_fetch_assoc($a);
  $number = $number_a['number']+1;`
```

That's how I got this variable.

```
echo '<input name="id" type="hidden" value="'.$number.'"  />';
```

That's how I pass it.

```
echo $number = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['id'] );
```

That's how I tried to get it in other php file.

Everything from other textareas passes just fine.

Full code as requested. ADD.PHP:

```
<?php
$dblocation = "127.0.0.1";
    $dbname = "tvp";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpasswd = "";
    $dbcnx = @mysql_connect($dblocation,$dbuser,$dbpasswd);
    if (!$dbcnx) 
    {
      echo( "<P>В настоящий момент сервер базы данных не доступен, поэтому 
                корректное отображение страницы невозможно.</P>" );
      exit();
    }
    if (!@mysql_select_db($dbname, $dbcnx)) 
    {
      echo( "<P>В настоящий момент база данных не доступна, поэтому
                корректное отображение страницы невозможно.</P>" );
      exit();
    }   

    echo '<form name="editform" action="adder.php" method="POST">'; 
  echo '<table>'; 
  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>Номер</td>'; 
  $a = mysql_query("SELECT number FROM peoples ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 1");
  $number_a = mysql_fetch_assoc($a);
  $number = $number_a['number']+1;


    echo $number;
    var_dump($number);
    print_r($number);
  echo '<td><textarea name="number" >'.$number.'</textarea></td>'; 
    echo '<input name="id" type="hidden" value="'.$number.'"  />';
  echo '</tr>'; 
  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>Имя</td>'; 
  echo '<td><textarea name="givenName">'.$man['givenName'].'</textarea></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>';
  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>Инициалы</td>'; 
  echo '<td><textarea name="middleInitial">'.$man['middleInitial'].'</textarea></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>';  
  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>Фамилия</td>'; 
  echo '<td><textarea name="surname">'.$man['surname'].'</textarea></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>'; 
 echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>Пол</td>'; 


      echo '<td>   <input type="radio" name="gender" value=1 >Man<Br>
       <input type="radio" name="browser" value=0>Woman<Br> </td>'; 
      echo '</tr>'; 



  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>Город</td>'; 
  echo '<td><textarea name="city">'.$man['city'].'</textarea></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>';     
    echo '<input name="id" type="hidden" value="'.$id.'"  />';
    echo '<input name="statee" type="hidden" value="'.$man['state'].'"  />';
  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>Штат</td>';

    ?>
    <td><select size="3" name="state">
    <option disabled>Выберите штат</option>
    <option value="AL" 
    <?php 
    if($man['state']=="AL"){
    echo "selected";
    }?>
    >Alabama
    </option>
    //...and so on...
   </select></td>
<?php
   echo '</tr>';    

        echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>Телефон</td>'; 
  echo '<td><textarea name="telephone">'.$man['telephone'].'</textarea></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>'; 

    echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>E-mail</td>'; 
  echo '<td><textarea name="emailAddress">'.$man['emailAddress'].'</textarea></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>'; 

      echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>Дата</td>'; 
  echo '<td><textarea name="birthday">'.$man['birthday'].'</textarea></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>'; 

    echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>Место работы</td>'; 
  echo '<td><textarea name="occupation">'.$man['occupation'].'</textarea></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>'; 
      echo '<tr>'; 
   echo '<td>Компания</td>'; 
  echo '<td><textarea name="company">'.$man['company'].'</textarea></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>';

  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>Вес</td>'; 
  echo '<td><textarea name="weight">'.$man['weight'].'</textarea></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>';

    echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>Рост</td>'; 
  echo '<td><textarea name="length">'.$man['length'].'</textarea></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>';

      echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>Адрес</td>'; 
  echo '<td><textarea name="streetAddress">'.$man['streetAddress'].'</textarea></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>';

  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>Почтовый индекс</td>'; 
  echo '<td><textarea name="zipCode">'.$man['zipCode'].'</textarea></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>';

    echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>Страна</td>'; 
  echo '<td><textarea name="country">'.$man['country'].'</textarea></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>';

    echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td><input type="submit" value="Сохранить"></td>'; 
  echo '<td><button type="button" onClick="history.back();">Отменить</button></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>'; 
  echo '</table>'; 
  echo '</form>'; 

  ?>
```

And ADDER.PHP:

```
<?php
$dblocation = "127.0.0.1";
    $dbname = "tvp";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpasswd = "";
    $dbcnx = @mysql_connect($dblocation,$dbuser,$dbpasswd);
    if (!$dbcnx) 
    {
      echo( "<P>В настоящий момент сервер базы данных не доступен, поэтому 
                корректное отображение страницы невозможно.</P>" );
      exit();
    }
    if (!@mysql_select_db($dbname, $dbcnx)) 
    {
      echo( "<P>В настоящий момент база данных не доступна, поэтому
                корректное отображение страницы невозможно.</P>" );
      exit();
    }

$number=$_POST["id"]; echo '<br>';
var_dump($_POST['id']);
print_r($POST['id']);
echo $number;
echo $givenName = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['givenName'] ); echo '<br>';
echo $middleInitial = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['middleInitial'] ); echo '<br>';
echo $surname = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['surname'] ); echo '<br>';
echo $gender = $_POST['gender'] ; echo '<br>';
echo $city = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['city'] ); echo '<br>';
echo $state = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['state'] );echo '<br>';
echo $emailAddress = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['emailAddress'] );  echo '<br>';
echo $telephone = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['telephone'] );  echo '<br>';
echo $birthday = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['birthday'] );  echo '<br>';
echo $occupation = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['occupation'] );echo '<br>';
echo $company = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['company'] );    echo '<br>';
echo $weight = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['weight'] );  echo '<br>';
echo $length = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['length'] );  echo '<br>';
echo $streetAddress = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['streetAddress'] );  echo '<br>';
echo $zipCode = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['zipCode'] );  echo '<br>';
echo $country = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['country'] );  echo '<br>'; 



    $query = "INSERT INTO peoples (number,givenName, middleInitial, surname, gender, city, state, emailAddress, telephone, birthday, occupation, company, weight, length, streetAddress, zipCode, country) VALUES ( '".$number."', '".$givenName."', '".$middleInitial."', '".$surname."', '".$gender."', '".$city."', '".$state."', '".$emailAddress."', '".$telephone."', '".$birthday."', '".$occupation."', '".$company."', '".$weight."', '".$length."', '".$streetAddress."', '".$zipCode."', '".$country."');";
  mysql_query ( $query );

    ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does `print_r($_POST)` say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is your re-assigning  the hidden field id at the bottom of your form

here

```
  echo '<td><textarea name="city">'.$man['city'].'</textarea></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>';     
    echo '<input name="id" type="hidden" value="'.$id.'"  />';     <------- HERE
    echo '<input name="statee" type="hidden" value="'.$man['state'].'"  />';
  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>Штат</td>';
```

i'm assuming you never assigned $id to number so, at the top of your form, yours assigning the hidden field id to "$number" but at the bottom of the form your assigning the hidden field id to $id. overwriting the original id field from the top of the form

Answer (score 1):

first things first. make sure you are echoing out the number to the screen. the code you have written looks correct but it's just a snippet.

add var_dump($number) after you assign your number and see if it's showing the number. if it's not then theres a problem with your sql

Comment: it shows int(10001) when I have just assigned it. But it somehow posts empty string

Answer (score 0):

You are `echo`ing!

```
echo $number = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['id'] );
```

Change that with:

```
$number = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['id'] );
echo $number;
```

If you wanna `echo` it.

Comment: well, yes, but that's just for testing and the problem is still here

Comment: Okay. Now can you get us the information about what is in the `$number` of `<input />` by viewing source, and also what is it you get in the `var_dump($_POST['id'])`?

Comment: var_dump says string(0) ""

Comment: Ah... Nice, now do you have any validations in this? Because this might be considered as an empty string and if you are checking for emptiness, this will return true!

Comment: @chuckieDub Oh okay. :) Thanks for letting know.

Comment: but there's one thing I forgot to change, in add.php there are some values in textfields but they shouldn't be there. That's just from other part of code. Only number field is set and disabled.